# Plotting points in python

Tags: python, plot

I want to plot some (x,y) points on the same graph and I don't need any special features at all short of support for polar coordinates which would be nice but not necessary. It's mostly for visualizing my data. Is there a simple way to do this? Matplotlib seems like way more than I need right now. Are there any more basic modules available? What do You recommend?

Comment: matplotlib is the way.. for plotting points you need just *2* lines, and then you have the possibility to easily make more complex stuff with the same tool :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go with [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) Chance is that sometime in the future you might need to do more than just "simple" stuff and then you don't need to invest time learning a new plot-tool.

See this [link](http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting) for list of plotting tools for python...

Answer (score 15):

Absolutely. Matplotlib is the way to go.

The [pyplot module](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) provides a nice interface to get simple plots up and running fast, especially if you are familiar with MatLab's plotting environment. Here is a simple example using pyplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x_points = xrange(0,9)
y_points = xrange(0,9)
p = ax.plot(x_points, y_points, 'b')
ax.set_xlabel('x-points')
ax.set_ylabel('y-points')
ax.set_title('Simple XY point plot')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
x = range(1,10) 
y = range(1,10) 
plt.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.show()
```

Here's a simple line with made up x, y. Note: **x** and **y** are lists.

Their lengths should be equal or you'll get a error. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the most good looking plotting library for Python: [CairoPlot](http://linil.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/cairoplot-11/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Tkinter canvas widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm). It uses rectangular coordinates but of course you can translate to polar. The canvas is pretty much just like it sounds -- a blank canvas on which you can draw points, lines, circles, rectangles, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could always write a plotting function that uses the `turtle` module from the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) is GPL plotting library which have Python interface, arbitrary (including polar) curved coordinates, a lot of plot types, export to PNG, EPS, SVG, widgets, and so on. For 1D plot samples see [here](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/web_en/web_en_4.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use pillow?

```
   from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

   #Set up canvas
   img = Image.new (mode, size)
   draw = ImageDraw.Draw (img)

   #Draw your points
   draw.point (xy, colour)
```