# dates from csv files , how can i graph it

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, graphics

I am new in using python.
I am trying to graph 2 variables in Y1  and Y2 (secondary y axis) , and the date in the x axis from a csv file.

I think my main problem is with converting the date in csv.

Moreover is it possible to save the 3 graphs according to the ID (A,B,C)... Thanks a lot.

I added the CSV file that I have and an image of the figure that i am looking for.

Thanks a lot for your advice

```
ID  date    Y1  Y2 
A   40480   136 83
A   41234   173 23
A   41395   180 29
A   41458   124 60
A   41861   158 27
A   42441   152 26
A   43009   155 51
A   43198   154 38
B   40409   185 71
B   40612   156 36
B   40628   165 39
B   40989   139 77
B   41346   138 20
B   41558   132 85
B   41872   157 58
B   41992   120 91
B   42245   139 43
B   42397   131 34
B   42745   114 68
C   40711   110 68
C   40837   156 38
C   40946   110 63
C   41186   161 46
C   41243   187 20
C   41494   122 55
C   41970   103 19
C   42183   148 78
C   42247   115 33
C   42435   132 92
C   42720   187 43
C   43228   127 28
C   43426   183 45
```

[image: graph expected]

Comment: could you share some more information?

Comment: Thanks for answering , i am trying to plot a graph for 2 values y1 and y2 , together with the date .. i put csv value above to make it clear and i also attached an example graph ,, let me know if it now clear

Comment: Have you tried anything? First off, you need to read the csv file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python?noredirect=1&lq=1 then you can use matplotlib to plot the contents https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819653/plotting-points-in-python

Comment: i can read the CSV file.  put i cant plot with date ... i know that sounds stupid.. but i am very new in python world.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the matplotlib library, if i understood right, it should work.

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
```

## Data for a three-dimensional line

```
zaxis = y1
xaxis = date
yaxis = y2
ax.plot3D(xaxis, yaxis, zaxis, 'red')
```

## Data for three-dimensional scattered points

```
zdat = y1
xdat = date
ydat = y2
ax.scatter3D(xdat, ydat, zdat, c=xdat, cmap='Greens')
```

Comment: thanks a lot but i need it as the following image in 2D not 3D
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DzRF.png

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html try this

Comment: I have problem with date

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for three separate graphs for ID=A, ID=B, ID=C. Here is how you could get that:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt

data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep='\t')  # read your datafile, you might have a different name here

for i, (label, subset) in enumerate(data.groupby('ID')):
    plt.subplot(131+i)
    plt.plot(subset['date'], subset['Y1'])
    plt.plot(subset['date'], subset['Y2'], 'o')
    plt.title('ID: {}'.format(label))
plt.show()
```

Note that this treats your dates as integers (same as in the datafile).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer , but i have the error
  for i, (label, subset) in enumerate(d.groupby('ID')):

NameError: name 'd' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I fixed it in my answer.

Comment: sorry for the late response , i was trying to figure the error out, but i couldnt , i sill have this error  raise KeyError(gpr)

Comment: You get a `KeyError`? How do the column names of your data frame look like? I suspect that one of the column names ('ID', 'date', 'Y1', 'Y2') is not there or is incorrectly spelled. For example, it might be that you have a column that pandas parsed as `'ID '`. Note the additional space? That's different from `'ID'`.

Comment: i am sorry for that , could it be that the .dat and my file is .csv, but i change it and still cant group with ID

Comment: What I used as input file, was simply the data from the example you have in your question. That appeared to be tab-separated data. You could also read the data will a regexp separator like so: `data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep='\s*', engine='python')`. If you want to check what column names were found in your data, you can use `data.columns`